# Java : Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

Method overloading with Wrapper class

```
void Test1(Object o)
{
    System.out.println("object");
}


void Test1(Integer o) 
{
System.out.println("Integer"); 
}

void Test1(Long o)
{
    System.out.println("Long");
}
```

Calling Test1(1) will call the Integer but when we call Test1(1) after commenting the method with Integer as text,it will call the method of Object text and not the Long one.

Again

```
void Test1(Object o)
{
    System.out.println("object");
}


void Test1(Integer o) 
{
System.out.println("Integer"); 
}

void Test1(Long o)
{
    System.out.println("Long");
}
void Test1(int o)
{
    System.out.println("int");
}
```

Also consider the case when we are calling Test1('a') so it will call int one. now remove the int one so it should call Integer one as 'a' will change to int and int will change to Integer but in that case it will call the Object one.
Any specific reason for the same ?

Comment: why it is not calling Long, if we comment the Integer one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autoboxing conversions, as specified in [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), are pretty specific. `int` will only ever convert to `Integer`.

So you have two overloads: one that takes a Long, and one that takes an Object. Note that Long does *not* extend Integer. So if you pass an argument of type Integer in, the Long method can't accept it. The only overload that can, is the one that takes Object.

Your confusion probably stems from one of two thoughts:

- either that the conversion will try `1` -> `1L` -> `Long.valueOf(1L)`
- or that Long extends Integer, so a method that takes Long can accept arguments of Integer

Neither of those is true in Java.

Comment: say we also have a int method, now we are calling Test1('a').... so int method get called. But if we remove the int method then Integer should get called . But in that case Object method get called ... why so ?

Comment: `'a'` is a char, so again, it will only get boxed to a `Character`. But a char primitive _can_ be automatically widened to an int primitive (even though a Character cannot be automatically cast to an Integer), so if you pass in a char, and there's an overload that accepts an int, then that overload is valid.

Answer (score 0):

**[Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)** class is a child class of **[Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)** class which is a child class of **[Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)** class.

**[Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)** is also a child class of Number class. But there is no direct hierarchical relationship between Integer and Long class (except both are child of Number).

If you comment the method with Integer, then as per to java inheritance it will see it's parent reference being (actually immediate parent reference would be Number but none of the methods have Number class in their signature) Object class and method signature matching it will be invoked. Hence you get output as "object".

Check the JLS link (from the other answer by @yshavit ) also for more details regarding why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `Test1(1)`, `1` is an int and not a long. Passing `1L` will pass as a long and will call the proper method.